# Javascript functions doesn't work in the new innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to angular js and i am working on monaca ide to make a hybrid app which uses onsen-ui and i wrote the following code and when the response comes from the server it isn't using the javascript methods for eg the {{"hello"}} at the last line is shown in the browser as {{"hello"}} only and because of that i think that the new code doesn't follow the rules of javascript files

```js
                  this.find=function(){
    //ajax start
    
            $http({
    method :"POST",
    url : "http://www.ashishmalgawa.xyz/rakt/finder.php",
   headers: {
   'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
 },    
   data: "date="+$rootScope.dob
  }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = response.data;
      $scope.search=false;
                
    }, function myError(response) {
      $scope.hellow = response.statusText;
  });
     
    //ajax end         
                   }
```

```html
<ons-list>
<?php
/* DBMS related code
*/
?>
 <ons-list-item ng-click="" modifier="tappable">
      <?php
            while($r=$re->fetch_assoc()){
                echo $r['name']."<br>";
                echo $r['gender']."<br>";
                echo "$distance kms away";
                
            }
         ?>
    </ons-list-item>
    <?php
    }
     }
}
else{
    echo "No Results Found";
}
$conn->close();         

?>
    </ons-list>
{{"hello"}}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this will not work, because `<ons-list>` etc, is not plain html, its an Angular component.

You should return a JSON of data, and then render it on the client side the angular way.

Comment: i know the correct way to do is to use JSON but i am not that much familiar with it that's why i tried to use this and can you please tell me why this will not work ?

Comment: Because you are trying to include angular directives by manipulation of the dom.. you simply cant do that, the directive is not html, it is an angular model, and should be managed by angular.

Comment: There is no such a thing as <ons-list> in HTML